# Definition of abstract method accepting type of implementing class only

Tags: java, generics

Objective: Define an abstract method which accepts a reference of type (or sub-type) of the implementing class.

What I came up with is:

```
public abstract class Parent<T extends Parent> {
    public abstract void foo(T t);
}
```

An implementation could be:

```
public class Child extends Parent<Child> {
    public void foo(Child child) { /* ... */ }
}
```

At first sight this looks like a satisfying solution, but it allows as well following implementation:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent<Child> {
    public void foo (Child child) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Is there a way to define the abstract method to prevent the second implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally possible to force that constraint in compilation time. However you can make it a bit more cumbersome to violate that constraint like so:

```
abstract class Parent<T extends Parent> {

   protected Parent(Class<T> clazz) {
      if (!this.getClass().equals(clazz))  {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("you must pass this; invalid attempt to extend Parent where subclass does not assign T to itself.
      }
   }
   // ...
}  

class GoodChild extends Parent<GoodChild> {
   public GoodChild() { super(GoodChild.class) };
}

class BadChild extends Parent<GoodChild> {
   public BadChild() { super(BadChild.class) }; // cannot compile.
}

class WorstChild extends Parent<GoodChild> {
   public WorstChild() { super(GoodChild.class); } // compiles but will fail in run-time.
}

class CircularChild extends Parent<Parent> {
   public CircularChild() { super(Parent.class); } // compiles but will fail
}
```

The trick is that the parent constructor code is binding in run-time the `this`'s class to be the same class as `T` that is what you want.

Comment: Notice that I've just have updated the answer to a more simple solution. after being voted up +1.